# ajax diagnose tool for internet explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, diagnostics

i am searching for a tool, that displays ajax requests in ie like firebug does it in ff.
do you know any free, easy 2 use , easy 2 install  ... add-on/plug in for IE (8)?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/?langage=en) - It's free for personal use.

Then there is: [Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx) of course.

And also: [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) which works in IE6+

Comment: oh cool debug bar did the trick! tanks.
bit ie dev-tool can't diagnose ajax.